# Calling a function of a class does not work php

Tags: php

I have a php file called "purchases.controller.php" in which within a function called 'ctrCash' of the 'Purchases' class, I pass variables to a function called 'ctrNewCashPurchase' of the 'CartController' class that I have defined, but when I run the project, I get the message:

> "Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Class 'CartModel' not found in ... "

If I do a var_dump inside the function ctrNewCashPurchase, I realize that I am entering that function, but it tells me that it does not recognize 'CartModel' and I do not understand why.

**I share the code of the "purchases.controller.php" file:**

```
class CartController{

    static public function ctrNewCashPurchase($datos){

        $tabla = "compras";

        $respuesta = CartModel::mdlNewCashPurchase($tabla, $datos);

        if($respuesta == "ok"){

            $tabla = "comentarios";
            ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresoComentarios($tabla, $datos);

        }

        return $respuesta;

    }      

}

class Purchases {

    public function ctrCash (&$arrayCompleto, &$usuario, &$direccion1, &$direccion2, &$dia, &$hora, &$email, &$telefono, &$sesion){

        if(isset($usuario)){

             //Here I create an array
             for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayCompleto); $i++){

               $datos = array("idUsuario"=> $sesion,
                              "idProducto"=> $arrayCompleto[$i]["idProducto"],
                              "metodo"=> "Efectivo",
                              "email"=> $email,
                              "direccion"=> $direccion1,
                              "detalleDireccion"=> $direccion2,
                              "diaEnvio"=> $dia,
                              "horaEnvio"=> $hora,
                              "telefono"=> $telefono,
                              "pais"=> "ARG");

                }

             $respuesta = CartController::ctrNewCashPurchase($datos);

          }

     }

}
```

**I share the code of the "purchases.model.php" file, where I define the CartModel class:**

```
class CartModel{

    static public function mdlNewCashPurchase($tabla, $datos){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (id_usuario, id_producto, metodo, email, direccion, pais, detalleDireccion, diaEnvio, horaEnvio, telefono) VALUES (:id_usuario, :id_producto, :metodo, :email, :direccion, :pais, :detalleDireccion, :diaEnvio, :horaEnvio, :telefono)");

        $stmt->bindParam(":id_usuario", $datos["idUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_producto", $datos["idProducto"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":metodo", $datos["metodo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datos["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":direccion", $datos["direccion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pais", $datos["pais"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":detalleDireccion", $datos["detalleDireccion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":diaEnvio", $datos["diaEnvio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":horaEnvio", $datos["horaEnvio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":telefono", $datos["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if($stmt->execute()){ 

            return "ok"; 

        }else{ 

            return "error"; 

        }

        $stmt->close();

        $tmt =null;
    }

}
```

**And I add this other file called 'aux.php' in case it influences something in the error that causes me. Here is how to send 'purchases.controller.php' parameters within the 'ctrCash' function**

```
    if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){

    require ('purchases.controller.php');

    $arrayCompleto = json_decode($_POST['arrayCompleto'], true);

$usuario = $_POST['usuario']; 
$direccion1 = $_POST['direccion1']; 
$direccion2 = $_POST['direccion2']; 
$dia = $_POST['dia']; 
$hora = $_POST['hora']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$telefono = $_POST['telefono']; 
$sesion = $_POST['sesion'];


 $payments = new Purchases(); 
$payments -> ctrCash($arrayCompleto, $usuario, $direccion1, $direccion2, $dia, $hora, $email, $telefono, $sesion);

    }
```

Comment: You haven't included "purchases.model.php"

Comment: @Second2None And where should I include it?

Comment: Depends on where you plan on using it. If just within purchases.controller.php you should be able to add it to the top of purchases.controller.php. You should look into extends you may benefit from it http://php.net/manual/it/keyword.extends.php

Comment: @Second2None Thanks! I will search